# routing in Node / express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var newproject = require('./routes/newProject');

var app = express();



// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/newproject', newproject);



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**newproject .js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sql = require ('mssql');

router.get('/newproject', function(req, res) {
    res.render('newProject');
});


module.exports = router;
```

**newProject.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
hello
</body>
</html>
```

and a similar index.ejs in views .

My home directory works ie `localhost:3000/` works but when i type 
`localhost:3000/newproject` it poses the following error :

> Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "F:\project\pcgWebApp\views"
>           at EventEmitter.render (F:\project\pcgWebApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
>           at ServerResponse.render (F:\project\pcgWebApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
>           at F:\project\pcgWebApp\app.js:47:7
>           at Layer.handle_error (F:\project\pcgWebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
>           at trim_prefix (F:\project\pcgWebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
>           at F:\project\pcgWebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>           at Function.process_params (F:\project\pcgWebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>           at next (F:\project\pcgWebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>           at F:\project\pcgWebApp\app.js:36:3
>           at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\project\pcgWebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

anyone know whats going on -  ?Please help - have tried doing npm install .

It does work if i place

```
router.get('/newproject', function(req, res) {
    res.render('newProject');
});
```

in app.js and change router to app.get..

Comment: But i want it be placed in newproject.js as i have to query a db in newProject.js and reder a lot of variables to the view

Comment: So i created a error.ejs in views  but instead of picking up the /newprojects route it now shows contents of error.ejs.

Comment: If my solution worked, select it as the accepted answer + consider giving it an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

In `newProject.js` change this:

```
//...
router.get('/newproject', function(req, res) {
    res.render('newProject');
});
```

For this:

```
//...
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('newProject');
});
```

Since newProject.js seems to be used as an external router, as you've written your code your final endpoint would be:

> localhost:3000/newproject/newproject

Instead, you want it to be:

> localhost:3000/newproject/

That's why you should specify '/' as the endpoint inside of your route: because **route paths in Express are associative**

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your first error is stemming from this section of code:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

More specifically, the part that is trying to render the `error` view. I would ensure that you have a `error.ejs` file / view in your views folder.

I would also change your `/newproject` root inside your new project.js file to just `/` as the root comes from the file name.

Comment: Thank you - this worked - i changed /newproject to /

Comment: Great and I can see you also added an error.ejs view which will have fixed your initial error. It's also probably worth marking mine (or the other answer) as accepted.